# Size constraints for custom view controller for NSToolbarItem

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, nstoolbaritem

I have a custom view in a toolbar. Sometime this year Apple deprecated `NSToolbarItem.minsize` & `maxsize`, and so now I get compiler warnings. How to replace the deprecated constraints in the current version of macOS for a custom view (drawn during runtime)? I have been searching and searching and I cannot figure it out.

Comment: FYI - Those two properties were deprecated in macOS 12, not "this year".

Comment: The deprecation warning states: *"This property is no longer recommended. Instead, let the system automatically measure the size of the view using constraints."*. So it seems you should make use of constraints as needed. Update your question with specific details about the toolbar item you are trying to create.

Comment: Agreed, I should use constraints "as needed."  However, for a custom view that is drawn dynamically at runtime, the stack, align, pin and resolve tools are unavailable in Xcode.  Since macOS 12 I get warnings if I try to set maxsize and minsize in my code.

Comment: You can setup constraints in code.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments.  As you see in what I have written above, that is the approach I have taken for years -- it does not work anymore.

Comment: As I stated before, update your question with your relevant code so someone can offer a proper alternative to using the deprecated properties.

Answer (score 0):

From [AppKit Release Notes for macOS 10.14](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/appkit-release-notes-for-macos-10_14#Automatically-Sized-Instances-of-NSToolbarItem):

> **Automatically Sized Instances of NSToolbarItem**
>
> Beginning in apps linked on the macOS 10.14 SDK, if an `NSToolbarItem` doesn’t have its `minSize` and `maxSize` properties set, these values are calculated automatically by AppKit using constraints, similar to how the size properties for `NSTouchBarItem` are set. (Previously, if the item’s minimum and maximum size properties weren’t set, the size of the containing view was used.) You can use constraints to define both a minimum and maximum size that will be calculated by AppKit.
> For example, you can create the following constraints to give the view a minimum width of 100 and a maximum width of 200:
>
> `view.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 100).isActive = true`
> `view.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 200).isActive = true`
>
> The same applies for height. Omitting a minimum width or height constraint will use the view’s intrinsic content size, which is automatically adjusted for localization purposes for controls.
>
> If the view being measured has an undefined height or width, the view’s frame size is used instead.